# Standard Field not shown in Standard Report

Tags: reporting, standard-objects

Using the standard report object: Opportunities, I need to group by the standard field: AccountSource.

[image]

The field is visible to all:

[image]

and required even

[image]

However, when using the report builder, the field is missing from the list

[image]

- It's a standard object, why don't I see it?
- Is that report: "Opportunities" is like a CRT? (Custom Report Type) - it does not make any sense

Comment: Weird; I double-checked in my dev org and sure enough it wasn't on that report either. I don't think I've ever seen that before.

Comment: but do you see it in the Account Object?

Comment: Yes; I see the field and was logged in with the System Admin profile, verified FLS, verified I was on the standard report. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that's annoying and dumb. I found [another complaint about this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giOjAAI), as well as looking for myself. But sure enough, it's not there.

Best workaround would be to create a new Formula(Text) field on Account or Opportunity. On Account, the formula would be `TEXT(AccountSource)`. On Opportunity, `TEXT(Account.AccountSource)`. You don't need to add the field to page layouts, and it will become available on the standard Opportunities report type.

Also, I [posted an Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l0D1AAI), which you're welcome to vote on.

Comment: I have a feeling that Idea will be released one day :-)